# Is it possible to find the limit of $\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The problem is as follows:

> A certain tv signal is modeled by the function shown below:
>
> $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}$
>
> where $a>0$
>
> Find the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$.

The alternatives given in this problem are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&-a\sqrt{2}\\
2.&\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}\\
3.&\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a}\\
4.&\sqrt{2}\\
5.&-\sqrt{a}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should I assess this problem?.

I'm confused about the simbol used in the limit but I think the intended meaning is to find the limit of the function where $x$ approaches to positive?.

Attempting to insert the zero in the function as it is given would yield an infinite value. Thus I thought to reduce the trigonometric expression by doing this:

$f(x)=\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}$

$\frac{1-\cos^2 ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}\times\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}{\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}$

$\frac{(1-\cos ax)(1+\cos ax )(\sqrt{1-\cos ax})}{x(1-\cos ax)}$

Simplifying terms in both denominator and numerator it yields

$\frac{(1+\cos ax )(\sqrt{1-\cos ax})}{x}$

By inserting the expression in the numerator inside the square root I'm getting:

$\frac{\sqrt{(1+\cos ax)^2(1-\cos ax})}{x}$

Expanding the whole expression I'm getting:

$\frac{\sqrt{(1^2+2\cos ax+\cos^2ax)(1-\cos ax})}{x}$

$\frac{\sqrt{1+2\cos ax+\cos^2ax-\cos ax-2\cos^2ax-\cos^3 ax}}{x}$

$\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos ax-\cos^2ax-\cos^3 ax}}{x}$

and that's how far I went. What exactly should be done here?. Can someone help me here?.

Comment: Hint: try going the 'other way'. Multiply numerator and denominator both by $\sqrt{1+\cos ax}$ and see what happens to the denominator.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Can you please be more specific?. If I attempted what you mentioned. I'm ending with this $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}\times\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos ax}}{\sqrt{1+\cos ax}}=\frac{\sin^2ax\sqrt{1+\cos ax}}{x(\sqrt{1-\cos^2ax})}$ this becomes into $\frac{\sin^2ax\sqrt{1+\cos ax}}{x(\sin ax)}= \frac{\sin ax \sqrt{1+\cos ax}}{x}$ but that's it. Where to go from there?. Can you give **more hints** or indicate **where to go** from here please?.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't know what should I do with the denominator as indicated in the above comment can you help me with that please?.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1,$$ we obtain:  $$\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}=\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt2\sin\frac{ax}{2}}\rightarrow\frac{a^2}{\sqrt2\cdot\frac{a}{2}}=a\sqrt2.$$

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I'm recovering from an infection illness hopefully not the virus.In my spare time I'm reviewing these concepts. Since its been a while I was taught limits. Where did you get the identity of $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$? Can you include a link for a proof of that?. I think the problem itself could had not been solved without knowing that fact. As for the rest I see you used half angle identity for simplifying the denominator. Am I right with this?. Hope you can help me with that. Hope you're in good health.

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjj2TsrhyVo This proof is not full, but it's enough for the first time, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{g^2(x)}=|g(x)|$

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 ax}{x \sqrt{2}~|\sin (ax/2)|} =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^2x^2}{x|ax/2|\sqrt{2}}$$
So $$RL=\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=a\sqrt{2}$$
and$$LL=\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=-a \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: $a>0$ and $x\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: @michael-rozenberg OK, see the edit

Comment: It's  given that $x\rightarrow0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the fraction with $\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos ax}}{\sqrt{1+\cos ax}}$.

So, you get for $a,x >0$

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\sin^2ax}{x\sqrt{1-\cos ax}}
& = & \frac{\sin ax}{ax}\cdot \frac{\sin ax}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 ax}} \cdot a \sqrt{1+\cos ax}\\
& \stackrel{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} & a\sqrt 2
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: As it has been mentioned before, how do I prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$? Is this part of an identity which I was unaware of?. Can you help me with this matter?.

Comment: This is a so called standard limit. Two quick ways to verify this limit are L'Hospital rule or using the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ of first order.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/2046827#2046827
Here you can see quite a few different ways how to prove this limit using different methods.